# Hello, is there any way of using transpose function in excel, that doesn't require fixed cell ranges

Tags: excel, transpose

Is there any way of using transpose function in excel, that doesn't require fixed cell ranges.

Example:
I have a table1 with cell ranges 10x5. I then define a transpose function in the range 5x10 `=transpose(table1)`. If I add another row in table1, cell ranges in table1 become 11x5. Since I only have defined transpose funtion in ranges 5x10, the new row doesn't transpose.

If I define transpose function in larger cell range than table (for example 15x7), I get cells with `#N/V`.

Is there any way that defined cell range for transpose function changes with changes in cell range of table?

Thank you in advance, 
blackfire

Comment: You will need vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: You'll need VBA to do this dynamically. If your just trying to get rid of the errors, wrap the larger range with IFERROR.